# OutputStreamWriter internal buffer size

Tags: java, java-io

I want to create an unbuffered `OutputStreamWriter`. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) (Java 7) say

> The resulting bytes are accumulated in a buffer before being written
>   to the underlying output stream. The size of this buffer may be
>   specified, but by default it is large enough for most purposes.

"The size of this buffer may be specified"... how?

(Edit: this was an old bug in the documentation; fixed in [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html))

Comment: Nice catch. I'd expect it to be in the constructor, but apparently not...

Comment: @JonSkeet Documentation bug? If so, it looks quite old... Weird. http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html

Comment: I believe _some_ buffer is outright required, because of the way character encoding works: if you receive the first half of a surrogate pair, you have to buffer that until you receive its second half.

Comment: @JonSkeet It should not be in constructor. If its there then there is no need for BufferedWritter

Comment: @SivaKumar: Yes there is - because a `BufferedWriter` doesn't do encoding. Assuming there's *any* buffering, it would make sense to be able to specify the size.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes. Once we can redefine the size it will be over head for the class.

Comment: @SivaKumar: In what possible way? There's already a buffer - if a caller specified a *smaller* buffer, that would be *less* overhead, surely. As Louis noted, there has to be a buffer of some description, and as I noted there's still a very significant difference between this and `BufferedWriter`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Actually that need must be implemented using a separated character buffer (raw), not by the (coded) byte buffer.

Comment: @LoudiWasserman That need concerns input: this question is about output.

Comment: @EJP: I'm not convinced?  An `OutputStreamWriter` receives `char`s, and you can receive one `char` and not yet be ready to convert it into bytes until you receive the other half of the surrogate pair.  @leonbloy: Max's answer below suggests that at least one `OutputStreamWriter` implementation _is_ using a character buffer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it seems that there is no way to tweak the buffer size. It was once possible to set the size in the constructor... in [Java 1.1](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.1-beta2-docs/api/java.io.OutputStreamWriter.html)!

The constructor dissapeared in [Java 1.2](http://www.cs.mun.ca/~michael/java/jdk1.2-docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) (1998) and apparently they forgot to update the documentation.

(It looks strange to me that this documentation bug has gone unnoticed so many years - and it also looks strange that I have no way to turn off the buffering.)

Update: still the same in [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

Update 2: acknowledged as [doc bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8179662), finally removed in [Java 9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) docs